# app wont run TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Ive been having this issue with map and have not been able to figure out why.

```
export default function() {
  return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {({ prices }) => (
        <PriceGrid>
          {prices.map((price, index) => (
            <PriceTile key={`priceTile-${index}`} index={index} price={price}/>
          ))}
        </PriceGrid>
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please also add the way you are filling in value variable. Also is it an array?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your react component (eg: where is `prices` being set? What is it being set to? What error is in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely prices is not an array at some point... you can do a type check and it will skip over if prices is of any type other than array;

```
      {Array.isArray(prices) && prices.map((price, index) => (
        <PriceTile key={`priceTile-${index}`} index={index} price={price}/>
      ))}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed this small error i have but now i am getitng another error so the app still wont open.

Comment: return (
   
 <AppContext.Consumer>
      {({ currentFavorite, coinList }) => (
        <Tile>
          <SpotlightName> {coinList[currentFavorite].CoinName} </SpotlightName>
          <CoinImage spotlight coin={coinList[currentFavorite]} />
        </Tile>
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  );
}

Comment: You will probably want to typecheck `coinList[currentFavorite]` which should be an object

Comment: how would i type it tho?

Comment: `coinList && coinList[currentFavorite] ? coinList[currentFavorite].CoinName : null`